# Enforcing Access Control on CouchDB

Tags: android, mobile, couchdb, replication, touchdb

I have been researching CouchDB and TouchDB for sometime now and seriously contemplating their suitability for a mobile app I have in mind. I have a few questions and I would really appreciate if anyone can point me in the right direction. The scenario is I have 2 mobile clients running on TouchDB. I want Mobile Client A to be able to replicate a specific document on to Mobile Client B. Then I want Mobile Client B to be able to make changes and sync those changes back to with Mobile Client A. From an architectural standpoint I figure that I would need a centralized couchdb database that both clients can pull/push. The problem that I am having is how do I ensure that Client B is only able to replicate documents that he is authorized replicate. I understand that I can use a replication filter to limit the documents that are replicated but how do I enforce it on Mobile Client B? Also what would be the ideal architecture for the above scenario? Any assistance will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a similar setup with TouchDB and BigCouch in EC2 (the centralized database). It can be quite an adventure to get the pushing and pulling working right. =)

I think you are on the right track with using a replication filter with the pulls. If you limit the pulls for Client B with a replication filter, your life will most likely be easier because Client B can modify anything on his local TouchDB and it won't hurt anything.

In other words, don't replicate down documents you don't want Client B to modify.

To do that you would have to introduce a field into the document that specifies an access level - or some array maybe that has Client B's user id in it. That way he only sees what he is authorized to see.

Two notes before I forget:  a) TouchDB on Android is sketchy right now.  They are working to make it better, but it's behind the iOS version. b) I strongly recommend looking into writing your replication filter in Erlang. I got a 50% speed increase from doing that.

Comment: Do you recommend storing the replication filter on the centralized server to push to Client B or sending filter to Client B and then do a pull?

Comment: I've put the replication filter on the centralized server. http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/EnableErlangViews That's how to enable Erlang filters if you want to try it.

Comment: Ok, I will check this out. Any gotcha's encountered while trying to make the pulling and pushing work right?

Comment: It wasn't always easy ... I'm trying to think of things off the top of my head. On the iOS side having an HTTP proxy (Charles, Fiddler) has been enormously helpful. I don't remember using one with my Android POC. Definitely don't be shy on the TouchDB forumn  (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mobile-couchbase). The main contributor answers stuff in like 20 minutes usually. Erlang filters are hard to write, but well worth it for efficiency. Spend time reading the Ektorp documentation. Hope that helps! Let me know if you have questions - I've been spending a lot of time on this lately.